# Showing Data Catalogue in Modal HTML with Javascript DOM

Tags: html, dom, event-listener

i have a question how can I put data image and text in the catalogue and show it in the modal by using dom javascript. Please help ..

**Modal html**

```
        <div
        class="modal fade"
        id="detail-article"
        data-bs-backdrop="static"
        data-bs-keyboard="false"
        tabindex="-1"
        aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel"
        aria-hidden="true"
      >
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title text-capitalize" id="modal-title">
                Modal title  ---->> this is i put the modal title
              </h5>
              <button
                type="button"
                class="btn-close"
                data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                aria-label="Close"
              ></button>
            </div>
            <div id="" class="modal-body">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                  <img id="modal-image" src="" class="w-100" alt="skilvul" />
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <p id="modal-text">Modal Text</p> --> this is where I put for modal text
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

The data I want to show; just title, thumbnail and text; here is id class i want to put in the modal: card-04-image, card-04-text, card-04-title.
**Here is my data of html:**

```
        <div id="card-04" class="card">
            <img
              id="card-04-image"
              src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1611854779393-1b2da9d400fe?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2940&q=30" ---> **this data**
              class="card-img-top"
              alt="skilvul"
            />
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 id="card-04-title" class="card-title text-capitalize">
                coffee grinder -->> **this data**
              </h5>
              <p id="card-04-text" class="card-text d-none">
                Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up
                the bulk of the card's content. ---> **this data**
              </p>
              <a
                card-id="04"
                href="#"
                class="stretched-link btn-modal"
                data-bs-toggle="modal"
                data-bs-target="#detail-article"
              ></a>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Here is my progress dom.js :

```
console.log(document);
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("modal"));
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("modal-dialog"));
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("modal-header"));
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("modal-content"));
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("modal-title"));
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("modal-body"));
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("button"));
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("modal-text"));
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("modal-image")); 

console.log(document.querySelector("#card-04"));
const card4 = document.querySelector("card-04");
card1.addEventListener("click", () => {
   getElementbyClassName("modal-title") = getElementsById("card-04-title").innerHTML;
   getElementsByClassName("modal-image") = getElementsById("card-04-thumbnail").innerHTML;
   getElementsByClassName("modal-text") = getElementsById("card-04-text").innerHTML;

});
```

i want to make the modal show data when I clicked them by using addEventListener. Please help me thanks. :(

Comment: `getElementbyClassName` returns a nodelist rather than a single element so you cannot simply assign a value to it. What is it that you `click` to open your `modal` to start this process?

Comment: That first piece of HTML has one too many closing `div` tags than opening and the last piece has two too many closing `div` elements. Is it somehow nested inside the other?

Comment: is it a button?

Comment: okay, i will fix that

Comment: @professor Abronsius its actually just a small part of whole code. I am sorry to copy it wrong :(

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap Or jQuery?

Comment: bootstrap only :)

Comment: Which version?!

Answer (score 0):

Is this something like you are trying to do?

I removed the ID attributes from elements as these will quite often cause issue if there are duplicates and there are alternative means of identifying elements within the DOM anyway. Without seeing a more complete example of the HTML structure the following may not accurately reflect the setup you have but can, most likely, be easily adapted to suit.

It appears that you wish to `open` the modal when clicking on the `div.card` element - presumably there are multiple `.card` elements so assign each an event listener as shown below by iterating through the `DOMNodeList` obtained using `document.querySelectorAll` ( I prefer that to `getElementsByClassName` but they both have merit )

The Event handler function `clickhandler` can use `this` to refer to the actual `div.card` element that invoked the function which allws you to easily identify DOM nodes within the `.card` using `querySelector`. It is then a case of assigning found items to the respective element within the `modal`

```js
const clickhandler=function(e){
  let modal=document.querySelector('.modal');
      modal.querySelector('img').src=this.querySelector('img').src;
      modal.querySelector('p[data-id="modal-text"]').innerHTML=this.querySelector('p.card-text').innerHTML;
      modal.querySelector('h5').innerHTML=this.querySelector('h5').innerHTML;
      
  
  modal.classList.add('open');
  modal.querySelector('button.btn-close').addEventListener('click',function(e){
      modal.classList.remove('open')
  });
};

document.querySelectorAll('.card').forEach( div=>div.addEventListener('click',clickhandler));
```

```css
.modal{ display:none; }
.modal.open{ max-width:500px; display:block; z-index:100; background:pink; border:5px solid red; }

.card{ border:2px solid blue; margin:1rem; padding:1rem; background:whitesmoke; cursor:pointer;}
.card .card-img-top,
.modal.open img{ width:300px }

h5{text-transform:upper;font-size:2.25rem}

.modal button.btn-close{padding:0.5rem;}
```

```html
<div class="modal fade" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title text-capitalize" id="modal-title">
          Modal title
        </h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">Close</button>
      </div>
      
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
        
          <h5 class="modal-title"></h5>
          
          <div class="col">
            <img src="" class="w-100" alt="skilvul" />
          </div>
          
          <div class="col">
            <p data-id="modal-text">Modal Text</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>






<div class="card">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1611854779393-1b2da9d400fe?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2940&q=30" class="card-img-top" alt="skilvul" />
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title text-capitalize">
      coffee grinder
    </h5>
    <p class="card-text d-none">
      Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.
    </p>
    <a href="#" class="stretched-link btn-modal" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#detail-article"></a>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="card">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/AZRynvM.jpeg" class="card-img-top" alt="skilvul" />
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title text-capitalize">
      Lovely cup of coffee
    </h5>
    <p class="card-text d-none">
      Some different text to illustrate that this is copied to the modal.
    </p>
    <a href="#" class="stretched-link btn-modal" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#detail-article"></a>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="card">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZTp9FSU.jpeg" class="card-img-top" alt="skilvul" />
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title text-capitalize">
      Guess what - more coffee
    </h5>
    <p class="card-text d-none">
      Lorem ipsum dolor solit... yada yada yada!.
    </p>
    <a href="#" class="stretched-link btn-modal" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#detail-article"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I will see your code tonight. :)

Comment: it works on image, but not for text and title on modal. anyway, thank you for your help

Comment: It should work for the text - but I omitted the title

Comment: what title? where?

Comment: You had no place in your modal for the title - where should it go?

Comment: it should be  <p id="modal-text">Modal Text</p> and <h5 class="modal-title text-capitalize" id="modal-title">     Modal title
              </h5>

Comment: OK but that was **not** in your original HTML

Comment: no, i had them. look at my modal html that I've written up above

Comment: Ok - I missed that! Apologies